# Fake mock location won't change on google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm verry new to android app creation, so i have a question:

Could you please tell me why real android device won't recognize mock (fake) location that is taken from jSON?

Function:

```
public void setLocation(double latitude, double longitude,Context ctx) {
          LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager)    ctx.getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (mLocationManager.getProvider("spoof") == null) {
                 mLocationManager.addTestProvider("spoof", false, true, false, false, false, false, false, 0, 5);
                 mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled("spoof", true);
                }
                 Location loc = new Location("spoof"); 
                 loc.setLatitude(latitude);
                 loc.setLongitude(longitude);
                 loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                 loc.setAccuracy(16F);
                 loc.setAltitude(0D);
                 loc.setBearing(0F);
                 mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation("spoof", loc); 
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Lat:"+latitude+" - Lng:"+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

So now i have `double` latitude and longitude and they are set as `lata`, `longa`

Here is the code that runs the function

`setLocation(lata,longa, getBaseContext());`

Function and sending data to function works, 'cause it prints out lat and long with `Toast.makeText`, but the problem is that google maps, google navigator won't see the new location and set is the real one.. it uses network location instead..

I've tried to run this on devices without GPS
 - Android 4.0.3
 - Android 4.2.2

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are using I suppose the new api?

Comment: @andrei what do you mean by "new api"? @SuppressLint("NewApi")?

Comment: the google maps api 2 I mean. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: @andrei hmm, I don't use google maps API, I just get ajax data and I try to change location for device.. I think it should work without including google maps api?

Comment: So you basically want to fake the location from the GPS device and then make it deliver a different location?

Comment: @andrei yes, I want to fake network location and move the "blinking blue dot" in other location

Comment: now the question, on which "thing" you see the blue dot? google maps, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the point, well what I did for this specific problem of yours is the following:
You have to create a class which extends the LocationSource like in the following example:

```
public class MyLocationSource implements LocationSource{

        //either save it or add it to a list
        //adivsable would be to create one instance for each listener not an array.
        OnLocationChangedListener listener;

        public MyLocationSource () {


        }
        //Google maps somehow extends this OnLocationChangedListener
        @Override
        public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener mListener) {
             this.listener =  mListener;
             //initially u save the listener
             //here u can make a mix between what the GPS delivers and your manual loc

        }

        @Override
        public void deactivate() {

           //here u can stop the updates
           listener = null;
        }


        protected void fireUpdate(Location loc) {

                if (listener != null && loc != null) {
                        listener.onLocationChanged(loc);
                }
        }
}
```

Now all you have to do in google maps is to instantiate this class and try providing with the locations you want using what I gave you. 
More details about activate/de-activate you can find at the following address:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.html 
Additionally you can take a look at commonswguy:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location

Comment: Hey, thank you, i did everything and got MockLocationListener.java from somewhere.. not everything is fine till onLocationChanged (inside MockLocationListener.java).. in log it show's that it works and stuff, but how can I make that Android thinks, that recieved info is the real one? - how to set it? Please check the mocklocationlistener java file: http://pastebin.com/r7uNPwVv

Comment: Well, basically you can try to look at the following link. http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/. But if I were you I would do it differently, I would create a class which extends the LocationListener and add some code to support both location from the GPS provider and the one set by and at the end just notify listeners. In your case maybe you didn't set in the manifest the mock location option.

Comment: Hi Andrei I know this is an older question but I'm trying do something similar. I'm trying to have a Service act as a mock location provider. What did you mean when you said "in google maps instantiate this class"? All the examples I can find seem to say use getMapAsync to register a callback to get the GoogleMap which I can then use to push a mock Location object. Do you know if you can set the location source for the actual Google Maps App? Thanks

Comment: Check this small project which is in progress: https://github.com/toaderandrei/live_tracking

Comment: This looks like you're still using your own map fragment, setting its location source and then providing a location source to your own map fragment (looking in LocationFragment.java). Is there a way to do it with the Google Maps app installed by default on the phone? Am I just looking in the wrong place?